# What are the available postdoctoral fellowships in Europe that non-European can apply for?

Tags: funding, postdocs, europe, marie-curie

In life Science, What are the available postdoctoral fellowships in Europe that non-European can apply for?

Once joined an EU research center can a non-EU researcher apply for Marie-Curie postdoctoral fellowships?
during a PD interview, PI said, it's not possible once the applicant already joined an EU center?

Comment: Europe-wide, I believe that Marie Curie is the only significant option. There might be a greater variety of options at the country level, but these will obviously differ from country to country.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question first, the Marie Curie fellowships require evidence of mobility - specifically, that you haven't worked in the proposed host country for more than 12 months total in the past three years. So if you join a lab in, say, France, after one year you will no longer be able to apply for a MSCA fellowship in France.

However, you'd still be eligible to apply for one hosted in any other EU country where you had not worked for more than 12 months in the past three years.

So, if you're happy and able to move labs, then you would still be eligible to apply for a MSCA fellowship. The full eligibility documents are on the call website if you want to read in more detail.

I don't think there's a short answer to your first question - the EU contains dozens of large scientific funders and probably hundreds of fellowship schemes, with differing requirements. There are likely search tools for specific countries/opportunities which would give a better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. Helpful and sad answer. May I know where can I find Life science related funding opportunities for Sweden and Finland if possible. Thank you again.

Comment: Finland and Sweden are outside my experience, unfortunately - I'm not familiar with any sites with good coverage there. Someone with local knowledge (and who may speak the language) may be more helpful there. Best of luck in your search.

Comment: In Finland the Academy of Finland is probably the first place to look (though I'm not in your field so there might be better sources of funding). Last year's call was here: https://www.aka.fi/en/research-funding/apply-for-funding/calls-for-applications/apply-now2/funding-for-research-post-as-postdoctoral-researcher-2020-all-research-fields/